# Check if directory exists with dynamic path

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

How can I check if the directory exists with a dynamic path (~) not a fixed path (C:)?

My code:

```
Soin_Id = Request.QueryString["SoinId"];
string path = @"~\Ordo\Soin_"+Soin_Id+@"\";
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    ASPxFileManager_Ordo.Settings.RootFolder = path;
}
else
{
    ASPxFileManager_Ordo.Settings.RootFolder =  @"~\Ordo\";
}
```

With this condition, it's never true, even though the directory exists.

Comment: is it a winform or a webform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to resolve dynamic path to physical path on server.

```
if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
```

also consider using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) for concatenation of path.